# How can I migrate after removing model "hidden" in my Django Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a hidden input in my models.py:

`hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

and proceeded to `makemigrations` and `migrate` my changes. After doing so, I decided to remove it and so i went and deleted the same line and did `makemigrations` although this time I got an error ending along the lines of:

`File "/opt/django/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/django/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'hidden'; check that column/key exists")`

Did I handle the situation incorrectly?

EDIT: I might have broken something. I went into my app/migrations and delete the migration file after

`./manage.py migrate my_app 0010_previous_migration`

Comment: Sounds fine, although Django seems to have got into a state where it thinks it has applied the first migration to create 'hidden', but the column wasn't created. Thus the second migration to remove 'hidden' then falls over. You could try manually adding the column with `alter table <tablename> add column hidden int not null;` and then re-run the migrations.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought i destroyed the whole app haha.